# unable to run laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I thought it was about time to look at a PHP Framework so I chose laravel. However, getting it running is causing me grief.

I followed the video from nettuts [installing laravel 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehY82-X9hBM) and at `5.05mins` into the video he uses the php command-line server command (available from 5.4) `php -S localhost:8888 -t public/` followed by confirming that it works via `localhost:8888` in the browser which displays 'Hello Wolrd!'

I have XAMPP installed and my version of PHP is 5.3.15. I attempted to test it by doing `http://localhost/learning-laravel/public/`

At this point I have already downloaded composer and installed the dependancies successfully.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning-laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning-laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learning-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Inside my learning-laravel folder I do have `bootstap/autoload.php`

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: how does your virtual host look like ?

Comment: @mpm: sorry, how do you mean virtual host? I'm fairly new to the configuration side of things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had another look at my folder structure and I noticed that composer had not run correctly and there were missing files. I've reinstalled it and it appears to be working.